# Mldivide in Parallel package

Tags: matlab

When the following line executes as part of parfor loop, its executes even if the G matrix is ill-conditioned.

```
betas = G\data.y2.';
```

However when I try to run it as part of a regular for loop the code stops executing and it reports that the Matrix is singular.

Why do the for and parfor loops handle it differently?

The reason I ask is that I am debugging some code that someone else wrote. I can't debug a parfor so I was hoping to find out what was happening by looking at the for equivalent.

Is there a way that I can debug parallel code where I can expect the code to behave the same way it would in the parallel environment?

Also what does `data.y2.`; mean as opposed to `data.y2'`;

Further I have an older version of the code that is designed to run purely in a regular for loop.

When I went back to run that I got the same error that stopped the code running.

However when I restarted MATLAB and ran it again it ran no problem. It simply takes the result of inverting the singular matrix to be `NaN` and continues (which is what I want).

In the parallel version the following declarations are made:

```
warnState(1) = warning('error', 'MATLAB:singularMatrix'); 
warnState(2) = warning('error', 'MATLAB:illConditionedMatrix');
```

Are these what are causing the code to stop?
If so why are they not affecting the parallel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference between regular desktop MATLAB and Parallel Computing Toolbox workers is that desktop MATLAB runs multithreaded, and workers run in single computational thread mode. I believe this can cause some slight numerical discrepancies. You can try launching your desktop MATLAB using

```
matlab -singleCompThread
```

to see if regular MATLAB can exhibit the same behaviour.

In MATLAB, the `.'` operator is `TRANSPOSE`, and `'` is `CTRANSPOSE` - the complex conjugate transpose.